# Autohotkey set windows position

Tags: autohotkey

I downloaded https://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/showoff/
I want to change window position.

line 21 I can see

```
Gui,Show,X%statusx% Y%statusy% W%statuswidth% H%statusheight% NoActivate,%applicationname%
```

but I can't see where's X and Y are set though I search through the file (I'm new to authotkey)

Comment: In the ini file.

Comment: @Oleg ah yeah thanks it works